# How do I call a Jenkinsfile Pipeline step from JobDSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

We bootstrap jobs onto our Jenkins 2 server using JobDSL (`pipelineJob`), and define their steps using Jenkinsfiles.

We need to call a Jenkinsfile Pipeline step from inside a JobDSL script, as a post action that responds to the success or failure of the build, after the job’s main Jenkinsfile has finished executing. (We cannot embed this particular step in the Jenkinsfile - it needs to live in the JobDSL definition.)

Can this be done, and if so how? (The ideal answer will include a minimum working `pipelineJob` example.)

Note 1: The steps for calling a JobDSL script from Jenkinsfile is well-documented in the jobdsl-plugin’s wiki, but despite much googling we have not seen instructions for the other way round.

Note 2: An example of a Pipeline step is `updateGitlabCommitStatus` from the [Jenkins Gitlab Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin).

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do that. Why can't you just add a post build action in the job that runs the Job DSL? Or within the Job DSL code you can invoke the GitLab API without the plugin, like:

def commentMr(projectId, mergeRequestIid, comment) {def body = comment
 .replaceAll(" ","%20")
 .replaceAll("/","%2F")
 def project = projectId
 .replaceAll("/","%2F")
 sh "curl http://gitlab:80/api/v4/projects/$project/merge_requests/$mergeRequestIid/notes -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdasdasdas' -X POST -d \"body="+body+"\""
}

Comment: Tomas - IIRC the Job DSL docs say that the pipelineJob type does not support publishers. I believe these to be synonymous with post-build actions, which would rule out that approach. Unless I am mistaken, and post-build actions are in fact supported by pipelineJob?